# Как выровнять по центру div

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

HTML:

```
<div id="oplatabutton">
   <iframe src="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/button-widget?targets=GramWay%20%22%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%22&default-sum=14990&button-text=11&any-card-payment-type=on&button-size=m&button-color=black&mail=on&successURL=&quickpay=small&account=410013809845735&" width="184" height="36" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь о выравнивании данного элемента по горизонтали внутри родительского, то для родительского элемента задайте

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Пример:

```css
.container {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
    <div id="oplatabutton">
        <iframe src="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/button-widget?targets=GramWay%20%22%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%22&default-sum=14990&button-text=11&any-card-payment-type=on&button-size=m&button-color=black&mail=on&successURL=&quickpay=small&account=410013809845735&" width="184" height="36" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

А можно без флексов )

```css
#oplatabutton {
  text-align: center
}
#oplatabutton span {
 display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="oplatabutton">
   <iframe src="https://money.yandex.ru/quickpay/button-widget?targets=GramWay%20%22%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%22&default-sum=14990&button-text=11&any-card-payment-type=on&button-size=m&button-color=black&mail=on&successURL=&quickpay=small&account=410013809845735&" width="184" height="36" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```